# if (self.n - FROM) % self.percent == 0:

Tags: python-2.7

trying to find out how to fix this and having all kinds of trouble since i know pretty much nothing about python and xml.

here is the whole error, any idea how to fix this?

> download_xml.py line 91, instart0
>   if (self.n - FROM) % self.percent == 0:
>   ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

and here is the actual part in the script:

```
def start0(self):
        self.n += 0
    if (self.n - FROM) % self.percent == 0:
            QtCore.QTimer().singleShot(100, lambda: self.upPercent((self.n - FROM) / self.percent))
        if self.n > TO:
            self.working_threads -= 1
```

Comment: Read the error message: "nteger division or modulo by zero"   Look at the line that is having the error.   It includes the modulo operator `%`therefor self.percent must be zero.  Your job as a programmer now is to figure out why and fix it.

Comment: if i knew how or why then i would know how to fix it but like i said i have 0 experience with this so that is why i am asking for help :)

Comment: I hate to be harsh, but The answer to "any idea how to fix this" is either "Learn Python" or "Hire a Programmer who knows Python."   If you decide to learn Python and run into problems, we can help, but you are really going to have to put in some effort yourself.  This is not a "write my program for me" site.]

Comment: i agree, so may i ask, if i would like to hire a programmer for this sort of thing, do you know how much it would cost? Would you be able to do it for me? for a price of course.